# Is there an equivilant of _set_purecall_handler() in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, gnu

I wanted to override the standard handler for pure virtual call (`__cxa_pure_virtual()`) with my own. Answer for Windows is '_set_purecall_handler()'.

Is there a similar facility in Linux/GNU?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You came so close to answering this question on your own. This is the source of `__cxa_pure_virtual` in [`gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/pure.cc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/libsupc%2B%2B/pure.cc?view=markup):

```
extern "C" void
__cxxabiv1::__cxa_pure_virtual (void)
{
  writestr ("pure virtual method called\n");
  std::terminate ();
}
```

So, there's no direct equivalent to Microsoft's `_set_purecall_handler` with GCC. However, since `std::terminate` is called by this function you can use `std::set_terminate` to set a handler that gets called after it prints the message.

Another possible solution is to provide your own definition of `__cxxabiv1::__cxa_pure_virtual` that overrides the library function. Something like this:

```
namespace __cxxabiv1 {
        extern "C" void
        __cxa_pure_virtual(void) {
                char const msg[] = "my pure virutal\n";
                write(2, msg, sizeof msg - 1);
                std::terminate();
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of your suggestions are to the point (and I did look at the source for pure.cc, but did not know about std::set_terminate()). In fact, std::terminate() is exactly what I wanted to bypass.

So `std::set_terminate()` is the (closest enough) answer!

Comment: So this is a weak symbol, otherwise it violates ODR.

Comment: @user877329 No __cxxabiv1::__cxa_pure_virtual isn't meant to be overridden, so it's just an ordinary symbol. As far as the C++ standard goes defining something with this name in your own code violates the rule against using identifiers with double underscores. So my second suggestion isn't portable, but it isn't meant to be. It's an alternative to using _set_purecall_handler, which is also not portable.

Comment: @RossRidge: There is a huge difference between being non-portable and undefined. `_set_purecall_handler` does not violate ODR so even though it is not portable, it is well defined. I tried to redefine `__cxa_pure_virtual` and I did not get any linker error, and it took my own, so it has to be a weak symbol, but `nm`lists it as `T`, strange.

Comment: @user877329 No, undefined just means that the standard doesn't define what happens. It doesn't mean that specific behaviour can't occur, it just means you can't depend on that behaviour being portable. In this case my second suggestion depends the following behaviours that aren't defined by the standard. 1) The compiler compiler generates code that calls __cxa_pure_virtual when a pure virtual function is called. 2) The linker prefers the definition of symbol in an object file over the definition in a library. It doesn't depend on the symbol in the library being weak. In fact, it's not.

Comment: @RossRidge But then it _is_ defined in `GCC` and `ld`. But only if it is in the official docs. I would not call `YourSystemSpecificFunction` undefined just because it is not mentioned in the C++ standard.

Comment: @user877329  Calling an API function like `open` or `CreateFile`, invokes undefined behaviour because these functions aren't defined by the standard. The fact that they're defined in other documents doesn't make them defined in Standard C++. Indeed a conforming implementation must let the code give different definitions of `open` and `CreateFile`. The one-definition-rule only applies to things defined in the code being compiled. It doesn't allow the implementation to define arbitrary identifiers that conforming code isn't allowed to define.

Comment: @RossRidge Really nasty things: Return pointer to local variable, calling free twice on the same pointer, write beyond allocated heap and stack boundaries, conditionals on uninitialized values, recursion without termination. This is what I call undefined behaviour errors. Things that an implementation cannot deal with in any good way, other than generating SIGSEGV and terminating the process. But perhaps these kind of things are called something else.

Comment: @user877329 Your definition of what undefined behaviour is differs from the C++ standard's definition. It just means that anything can happen. What you expect to happen, a compiler error, random crashes, or starting Minecraft are all things allowed to happen when you invoke undefined behaviour. According to the standard using __set_purecall_handler could cause any of the nasty things you described. There's no guarantee they won't happen. Maybe some other compiler happens to use the same symbol differently. Maybe it becomes one of the many interfaces Microsoft is changing in VS 2015.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82863/discussion-between-user877329-and-ross-ridge).

Answer (score 0):

Without any extra warnings enabled at all g++ (4.5 tested) will tell you that you're calling an abstract function from a constructor/destructor, which should nullify any need to set a custom handler.

Since a valid C++ program would never result in a pure virtual call, I assume you have this handler set on Windows for diagnostic/debugging purposes. In this case it seems far easier to diagnose at compile time rather than runtime.

Comment: No. I am not talking about compile time error handling. This question is about "run-time" exception handling (ie whenever `__cxa_pure_virtual()` gets called).

Comment: No, I have not set this handler in Windows. I just searched for it and the answer and I found was for Windows only. And yes, a Linux g++ compiled application can and does end up in this call at run time. The specific application under question does not have any compile time errors. It's a complex multi-threaded application, where instances of a derived class object just happen to 'disappear' at runtime, resulting in system exception of this 'pure virtual call'.

Comment: FYI here is gdb output: Here is gdb backtrace for this case: `#5  0x4015b7f4 in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_pure_virtual ()
    at XXXX/src/gcc/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/pure.cc:55
`